# MySql Workbench Schema Privileges panel is truncated and I can't access the Add Entry button

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying set schema privileges for a new user in MySQL Workbench 6.3 ce, but in the Schema Privileges dialogue the schema list box and options checkbox panel does not span the whole dialogue area, so that the Add Entry button is not accessible. Does any one know how to fix this? Unfortunately I am not permitted to show a screen shot.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to uninstall it and re-install 6.2.5, by clicking "Previous GA version" from download page. It was back to the old, black Home screen, my connections were still there from 6.3.x and the UI glitch is gone.